# Ext.ComponentQuery JSP ID lookup

Tags: extjs4

I have a panel and I can lookup this panel fine using:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('banner');
```

this returns the current component. This panel uses a loader and loads a jsp page into it. Can I use Ext.ComponentQuery.query to lookup ? I tried :

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('banner > #myId');
```

But it doesn't find it I'm guess it can't look up components that aren't EXT based?

I then tried:

```
Ext.dom.Query.select('myId');
```

And that works I get the HtmlElement back. But didn't know if  Ext.ComponentQuery could also find it?

What I want to do is add an onclick event listener to the HTMLElement that my Ext.Controller can listen for. When I used the Ext.dom.Query.select('myId');
I tried adding a listener as follow but it doesn't work it says attachEvent is not a function.

```
 el.attachEvent('onclick', function(){alert('hello!!!!')});
```

Comment: so iwas able to attach it as follows using the Ext.dom.Query.select('myId'); Then adding it as follows el.onclick=function(){alert('hello')}. I was just hoping to use the Ext.ComponentQuery.query but it make sense that you can't.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to attach it as follows using the

```
  var el = Ext.dom.Query.select('myId');
```

Then adding it as follows.

```
 el.onclick=function(){alert('hello');}.
```

I was just hoping to use the Ext.ComponentQuery.query but it make sense that you can't and that its just for EXT Components. But I get the same results in the end.